What is the best way to get rid of most of this wall texture?
My house has this very ugly wall texture: https://imgur.com/KCUE9LE
It has a few chips in some places (see the picture) but doesn't just peel off.
What's the best way to remove this? Will a sander like the Festool Planex work? I also considered skim coating, but the bumps are very high so I want to try smoothing those down first. Will the skim coat even stick to the current slick paint surface? If I do this without a power sander, what are the best tools to knock down the texture?
Trying to consider all my options (cheapest, easiest, etc.). Thanks.
Also, can anyone identify this wall texture? I've just been calling it "pimple."

wood chip paper?

I am afraid I will have to repectfully disagree with RMDman. I have done many drywall repairs with orange peel finish, which is what you do have.
I have seen improper prep done where the drywall mud didn't stay on the wall and the overlying paint came off with it. It did have help coming off, but in my opinion, proper prep would have kept it there.
I do sand all my repair surfaces for 2 reasons. First to give the surface "tooth" to allow the new material to grab the original surface. Years of whatever is in the air does effect the surfaces of walls and does require some cleaning or prep of some kind. Sanding in my opinon removes all doubt "did I get it clean enough?" This will require the removal of the dust afterwards, by vacuuming or at least a thorough dusting, which could really get dusty, if you know what I mean.
The other reason is to make the surface more smooth that what it is. This will take much less mud to make smooth since all the high spots are taken down by sanding. In addition, the sanded surface will allow the drywall tool to go over the surface without the bumpity-bump of riding over the texture. It wil dry faster too, since the mud will need to go on as thick.
To do the sanding, you can use the Festool as you mentioned, I didn't look it up, but based on what I see on jobsites that have the Festool brand being used, they have a HEPA vac to collect dust as is is generated. It is a pricy setup.
I myself have not done whole rooms, as mentioned just repairs. I have skimmed whole rooms, but not done in orange peel texture. Just window and door installs which required replicating the texture. The process is the same, but you will not need to spray the texture, in your case.
When I have the need to make these repairs, I have my 5" random orbit sander with a vacuum attached to it, and a supply of 40 grit sanding disks. It knocks it down pretty quickly. It is easy to gauge how the progress is since the tops will knock down right away but to sand all the way through, may take some doing, since the paint is tough to sand through at that level, at least is for me, especially for larger repairs. It is a tough workout.
Once it is down flat enough to skim, you could use a primer to seal the surface, some may reccomend it, but for my smaller repairs, I skimmed right over the dusted, vacuumed area.
A tip I seen the pros do and I have adopted. Using my 12" knife which is cambered, I add mud to the walls in stripes about 8" apart. The camber of the trowel wll let the edges of the knife ride on the sanded surface and the middle of the knife will leave a thin deposit of mud. After that dries, do the same thing again, using the dried mud you just applied to let the knife now ride on that mud to fill in the places between the first passes. Let dry then sand smooth ready for finishing.

@ Jack,  I respectfully disagree about sanding, but do whole heartedly agree about the wall needing to be very clean.  I totally like the 12 inch knife method and finally wonder how someone with this question has a Festool Planex!

I am curious about the Planex too. I just looked it up and it is a drywall sanding rig- nice... @RMDman , have you ever tried sanding first? I used to mud directly over the orange peel without sanding, and it left a lot of roughness to what could be an otherwise very smooth surface straight from the knife, so I started sanding and havent' regretted it. Just recalling my experiences. What is the cons of sanding? Perhaps there is something I haven't considered.

When I sanded, it would break the skin of the paint, then I would have issues with the compound not holding in some areas. The dust was also an issue. If I didn't get all the dust off, the compound wouldn't stick.  It was more efficient for me to not sand,( eliminate the paint and dust issue) and do 2 coats of skimming. I found the process went faster, with less issues.  I guess if you have a small area and all day to sand and clean it would be a better way, but longer in labor time.  I'm getting too old. I want my time to myself.

Thanks for the answers guys. I'm still mulling this over before trying the recommendations. Also to clarify, I don't have a Festool Planex, but while researching drywall sanders I saw it was often recommended as the one of the best/most powerful, which I would assume I need on painted walls. It's very expensive so I wanted more opinions instead of just buying.

The texture is an Orange Peel. There are many variations.
If you want a smooth wall the best technique is to skim coat with drywall compound, then sand.  Sanding before skimming is not needed and is actually a waste of time. When applying the skim coat, vary the pressure you are using on the drywall knife to see what gives the best result. ( Too much pressure will leave too many bumps. But they can be lightly sanded and gone over with a second coat.)
Yes the drywall compound will stick to the wall without sanding first.  The wall just needs to be clean and oil free. Power sanding is not recommended.
